# Azure blobs - cannot display image store in blob container in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

**Question background:**

I have a basic MVC 4 site and am trying to display a picture  that is stored in a blob storage container in my Azure cloud account. I store a list of image `Uri's` in a string `List` and pass these to a `View` where they should display

**The Issue:**

**I can't seem to get the file name of the image stored in the container.**

The following image shows the container in Azure. **Note** that there is an image stored in it with a size of 101.28KB:

[image]

This is the code I am trying to use to retrieve the blobs and then read the image `Uri's`:

`AzureStorageController` with a `Pics` Action Method:

```
 public ActionResult Pics()
    {
        var imageList = new List<string>();

        var imagesAzure = new myBlobStorageService();

        var container = imagesAzure.GetCloudBlobContainer();

        foreach (var blobItem in container.ListBlobs())
        {
            imageList.Add(blobItem.Uri.ToString());
        }
        return View(imageList);
    }
```

The `GetCloudBlobContainer` Method of the `myBlobStorageService` class:

```
 public CloudBlobContainer GetCloudBlobContainer()
    {
        string accountName = "fmfcpics";

        string accountKey = "xxxxxx/yyyyyyyyy/3333333333==";

        StorageCredentials credentials = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);

        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("images");

        if (container.CreateIfNotExists())
        {
            container.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions() { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });
        }

        return container;
    }
```

The `Pics` View:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Pics";
}

<h2>Pics</h2>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <img src="@item" alt="picture" width="200" height="200" />
}
```

The Uri that is in the list that is being passed to the Pics View is: **https://fmfcpics.blob.core.windows.net/images/myblob** but it does not feature the image file name.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: You should return the image itself from the blob. The way you are doing, using the url directly will not work, because the app has not permision to access the storage account.

Comment: Please check the ACL of the blob container and make sure it is not "Private".

Comment: You should close this question, since I answered your other question about blob-naming, which happens to answer this question as well. TL;DR: You *are* returning the blob name, which is `myblob`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Guarav has stated already, a good thing to check would be to make sure your container is not "Private".